# Update entity in jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

How can I update every fields in Entity without write sql query:

```
(update Entity u set u.m1= ?1, u.m2= ?2, ... where u.id = ?3)
```

Class has 20+ fields and if I write sql query This will take a long time. And I often add new fields

Can I update everything automatically? Like this:

```
entityRepo.update(entity);
```

If i do `entityRepo.save();` create unnecessary record in base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use `JpaRepository.save(S entity)` that saves **or** updates the entity if existing.
To achieve that, make sure that the entity has its JPA `@Id` valued before invoking `save()` otherwise a new record will indeed be created.

Comment: Even easier: if the entity is still attached (i.e. the transaction is not closed), you can simply update the object. The changes will be flushed when the transaction is comitted.

Comment: @Turing85, that is right. `JpaRepository.save()`  does simply `em.merge(entity);`  (that attaches the entity) for existing entities.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to [@davidxxx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56825266/4216641).

If the transaction with which the entity was fetched is not yet closed (i.e. the entity is still attached), you can simply update the java-object and the changes will be committed to the database when the transaction is committed.

Comment: Excellent alternative.